# What does Tifa's bar name mean?

Tags: final-fantasy

[7th Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Heaven) is the highest of Seven Heavens according to Islam and Judaism, but what do the signs say? The closest font i found is Deutsch_gothic:

[image: Deutsch Gothic font sample]
[image: Final Fantasy 7th Heaven bar front screenshot]

> Texas Cowboy Old Gyver [giver, shackler] bar?

Not a G.

"Cuuer bar"? "Cuter bar"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's Tyfer. (Pronounced "Tee-fa" rhymes with "key-ma", though there's disagreement online about the length of the last sylable).

It's named after the owner Tifa (a name in it's own right or Tiffany for short), (from [Tifa Lockhart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tifa_Lockhart)) rendered in [Romanisation or Romaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese) a way of representing Japanese pronunciation in English:

> it becomes
> “Tifaa”. The “aa” sound in Japanese is also used to approximate the
> sound of the English “er”, a combination for which the language lacks
> an accurate way to write.

<sup>[Glitterberry.com/Finalfantasy VII](https://www.glitterberri.com/final-fantasy-vii/map-analysis/map-analysis-part-5/) Jan 22nd 2011.</sup>

[image: Image of the word Tyfer in curly script]

**Edit:** In response to Austin Hemmelgarn's comment, the name Tifa (from [Tifa Lockhart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tifa_Lockhart)) started in western script, going through some process of transcription to Japanese and then in reverse to Western again. The standard methods to approach this are to use [Hepburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization), [Kunrei-shiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunrei-shiki_romanization), [JSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSL_romanization) or [Nihon-shiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihon-shiki_romanization) Romanisations. The OP of this answer has been unable to determine which was (were) used in either direction, but many opinions on the net (none worth directly referencing) indicate that it was at the discretion of the graphic artist rather than a translator, as-such.

Comment: Without playing the game with a mod installed to capture it as the OP did in their answer, I can't do better than the image in the question, I did search. @DavidW

Comment: That’s not kana, that’s [romaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese). The kana would be ティファ.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Ahh, that makes perfect sense thanks. I should have gone further in my researches, I'll look into editing in something appropriate.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Yeah, writing systems for the Japanese language are an almost comically complex subject. I think it may be the only language in widespread usage that involves four different writing systems in regular usage (kanji for the majority of the language, hiragana for inflections, particles, and native words with no kanji, katakana for roughly the same things italics are used for in languages with Latin scripts, and romaji for literate accessibility and inputting kanji and kana on computers).

Comment: Quite, the more I look into it, the more difficult it becomes to define the exact path of transcription from Western->Japanese->Western again. I might need to leave a note to that effect in the answer, maybe even making it a community wiki so if anyone can pin it down, they're welcome to. @AustinHemmelgarn Ahh, that's a thought, I wonder if a Japanese version of the logo can be found....

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: when you [edit] in a correction, you can and should fix the original mis-statement, not just add more text later.  i.e. you should fix the sentence before the quote block that says it's Kana, because it's not.  It's (if I understand correctly) a Romanji version of the Kana transliteration of "Tifa".

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, just getting used to the site's ways. Done satisfactorily now I hope.

Answer (score 4):

I've downloaded Omzy's FFVII Field Pack, "A 100% complete collection of 4x-resized background textures for FFVII." which doesn't really clear up the letter:

[image: 7th Heaven bar sign with different name]

But [Satsuki Yatoshi Mod - SYW V5.32](http://forums.qhimm.com/index.php?topic=20434.0) does:

[image]

```
TEXAS
COWBOY SALOON
DARTBEDS & BUDDIES?

Tuver [pigeon pea]?
BAR
```

Comment: If anything, the second character is a "Y," not a "U." And just based on proportions, the third character is closer to an "F" than anything else, with maybe "L" as a second choice.

Comment: That looks a lot like TYGER - the second and third cars are not exactly the same...

Comment: According to [A Rogue Ant's link](https://www.glitterberri.com/final-fantasy-vii/map-analysis/map-analysis-part-5/) it's "COWBOY CLUB" and "Tyfer BAR". But it looks like "COWBOY OLD SALOON 10 TV&BEER" to me. [SYW uses AI, which can change letters.](https://youtu.be/C9tMM9Ru2ls?t=19)

Comment: Especially after the photo of the mat in the other answer, I'm positive this image is also Tyfer.

Comment: An anonymous user said the top sign says "DRAFT BEER" on the left.